Ho do I write a formula that converts hours, but only if the date is within a specific range stored in other table?
VBA and PowerQuery / Power BI are not an option for reasons.
Given that, I know what I need is possible, I'm just having the hardest time getting to the how.
I have 4 worksheets.  One worksheet has employees and dates (broken out by week, so 10/13, 10/14, etc, etc) (examples to follow, if I can figure it out).  Sheet 2 has clock in/clock out data that is used to fill in numbers for that employee on that date in Sheet 1.  That part is working just fine.  Sheet 4 has holidays, so we override time worked with a code for holidays.  That part is working just fine.  Sheet 3 and vacation time is where the problem comes in.  Sheet 3 has the list of employees and separate entries for each vacation period.  Problem is, it has a total number of hours taken, a begin date and an end date, and I need to convert those to hours on a given day so that I can populate that date on sheet 1 with the vacation code and number of hours taken on that day.
Example (and I'll use employee codes, rather than names for privacy and because that's our index anyway.
Sheet 1:



Employee ID
10/8
10/9
10/10




80332
8.00
VAC24
8.00



Sheet 4:



Employee ID
Start Date
End Date
Hours




80332
10/9/24
10/10/24
16


80332
10/16/24
10/20/24
12



And so, I need Sheet 1 to say VAC8 on 10/9 and 10/10
The formula currently in use puts "Vac24" in 10/9, but does nothing for 10/10 or beyond and is shown here (yes, it does a lot of other stuff, as well):
=IF(AND(RIGHT($F80, 3)="(S)", COUNTIFS(Holidays!$A:$A, K$2)\>0), "HOL8", IF(SUMIFS(VacationImport!$F:$F, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E80, VacationImport!$D:$D, K$2, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken")\>0, CONCAT("VAC", SUMIFS(VacationImport!$F:$F, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E80, VacationImport!$D:$D, K$2)), IF(AND(RIGHT($F80, 3)="(S)", MOD(K$2, 7)\>1), 8, IF(H80="","", IF(SUMIFS(HJImport!$F:$F, HJImport!$C:$C, K$2, HJImport!$A:$A, $E80)\>0, SUMIFS(HJImport!$F:$F, HJImport!$C:$C, K$2, HJImport!$A:$A, $E80), IF(SUM(SUMIFS(TLImport!$G:$G, TLImport!$B:$B, $E80, TLImport!$L:$L, K$2), SUMIFS(TLImport!$H:$H, TLImport!$B:$B, $E80, TLImport!$L:$L, K$2))\>0, SUM(SUMIFS(TLImport!$G:$G, TLImport!$B:$B, $E80, TLImport!$L:$L, K$2), SUMIFS(TLImport!$H:$H, TLImport!$B:$B, $E80, TLImport!$L:$L, K$2)), 0))))))

Can anybody help me figure this out?
Edit:  So...I've got something working, but it's a huge cludge.  Can anybody help me clean it up?  It's also pulling an extra day on the beginning, so...no perfect.  Here it is:
=IF(AND(RIGHT($F189, 3)="(S)", COUNTIFS(Holidays!$A:$A, H$2)>0, $G189<(TODAY()-365)), "HOL8", IF(SUM(SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$N:$N, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$O:$O, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$P:$P, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$Q:$Q, H$2),  SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$R:$R, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$S:$S, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$T:$T, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$Q:$Q, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$R:$R, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$S:$S, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$T:$T, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$U:$U, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$V:$V, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$W:$W, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$X:$X, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$Y:$Y, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$Z:$Z, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$AA:$AA, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$AB:$AB, H$2, VacationImport!$AC:$AC, H$2),  SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$AD:$AD, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$AE:$AE, H$2),  SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$AF:$AF, H$2, VacationImport!$AG:$AG, H$2))>0, CONCAT("VAC", SUM(SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$N:$N, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$O:$O, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$P:$P, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$Q:$Q, H$2),  SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$R:$R, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$S:$S, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$T:$T, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$Q:$Q, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$R:$R, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$S:$S, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$T:$T, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$U:$U, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$V:$V, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$W:$W, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$X:$X, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$Y:$Y, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$Z:$Z, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$AA:$AA, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$AB:$AB, H$2, VacationImport!$AC:$AC, H$2),  SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$AD:$AD, H$2), SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$AE:$AE, H$2),  SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E189, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$AF:$AF, H$2, VacationImport!$AG:$AG, H$2))), IF(AND(RIGHT($F189, 3)="(S)", MOD(H$2, 7)>1), 8, IF(E189="","", IF(SUMIFS(HJImport!$F:$F, HJImport!$C:$C, H$2, HJImport!$A:$A, $E189)>0, SUMIFS(HJImport!$F:$F, HJImport!$C:$C, H$2, HJImport!$A:$A, $E189), IF(SUM(SUMIFS(TLImport!$G:$G, TLImport!$B:$B, $E189, TLImport!$L:$L, H$2), SUMIFS(TLImport!$H:$H, TLImport!$B:$B, $E189, TLImport!$L:$L, H$2))>0, SUM(SUMIFS(TLImport!$G:$G, TLImport!$B:$B, $E189, TLImport!$L:$L, H$2), SUMIFS(TLImport!$H:$H, TLImport!$B:$B, $E189, TLImport!$L:$L, H$2)), 0))))))

I figured it out, but it's a HUGE cludge, so any help optimizing it would be greatly appreciated.  Final code:
=IF(AND(RIGHT($F295, 3)="(S)", COUNTIFS(Holidays!$A:$A, H$2)>0, $G295<(TODAY()-365)), "HOL8", IF(SUM(
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$N:$N, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$O:$O, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$P:$P, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$Q:$Q, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken",VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation",  VacationImport!$R:$R, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$S:$S, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$T:$T, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$U:$U, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$V:$V, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$W:$W, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken",VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation",  VacationImport!$X:$X, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$Y:$Y, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$Z:$Z, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken",VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation",  VacationImport!$AA:$AA, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$AB:$AB, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$AC:$AC, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$AD:$AD, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$AE:$AE, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$AF:$AF, H$2))>0,
CONCAT("VAC", SUM(
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$N:$N, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$O:$O, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$P:$P, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$Q:$Q, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$R:$R, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$S:$S, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$T:$T, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$U:$U, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$V:$V, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$W:$W, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$X:$X, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$Y:$Y, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$Z:$Z, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$AA:$AA, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$AB:$AB, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$AC:$AC, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$AD:$AD, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$AE:$AE, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$AF:$AF, H$2))),
IF(AND(RIGHT($F295, 3)="(S)", MOD(H$2, 7)>1), 8, IF(E295="","", IF(SUMIFS(HJImport!$F:$F, HJImport!$C:$C, H$2, HJImport!$A:$A, $E295)>0, SUMIFS(HJImport!$F:$F, HJImport!$C:$C, H$2, HJImport!$A:$A, $E295), IF(SUM(SUMIFS(TLImport!$G:$G, TLImport!$B:$B, $E295, TLImport!$L:$L, H$2), SUMIFS(TLImport!$H:$H, TLImport!$B:$B, $E295, TLImport!$L:$L, H$2))>0, SUM(SUMIFS(TLImport!$G:$G, TLImport!$B:$B, $E295, TLImport!$L:$L, H$2), SUMIFS(TLImport!$H:$H, TLImport!$B:$B, $E295, TLImport!$L:$L, H$2)), 0))))))


I think a larger sample of your data and expected result may be useful here. Also, I have no idea what cells your formulas refers to. Why should 10/9 be VAC8 and not something else? Is it the average of 10/8 and 10/10? You mention clock in /clock out data, but I don't see that anywhere

I agree with cybernetic.nomad. you say you tell a long story involving sheet 1 to 4. You show 1 sample row for sheet 1 with 2 sample lines of sheet 4 jumping to a conclusion without explaining it. The formulas shared below could surely be optimized, but it starts with optimizing your question. Make it to the point and share samples and explanation that is reproducable.

What version of Excel are you using?  Later versions have functions such as LET, BYROW, BYCOL and MAP or SCAN which could be useful very here

Thank you all.  I do have Excel 365, so that's a plus.  I am still figuring out the formatting for Stack Overflow, so please, bear with me.  Thank you.

I'm not sure about your mammoth 41-line formula as, from all of the logic being contained within an AND() function, nested within an IF() function, I believe the output could only be either TRUE or FALSE.
Assuming, however, that it has some foundation in reality the section below
SUM(
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$N:$N, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$O:$O, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$P:$P, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$Q:$Q, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken",VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation",  VacationImport!$R:$R, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$S:$S, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$T:$T, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$U:$U, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$V:$V, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$W:$W, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken",VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation",  VacationImport!$X:$X, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$Y:$Y, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$Z:$Z, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken",VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation",  VacationImport!$AA:$AA, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$AB:$AB, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$AC:$AC, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$AD:$AD, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$AE:$AE, H$2),
SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", VacationImport!$AF:$AF, H$2))

which, since it appears to be duplicated, accounts for the bulk of the formula length, can be condensed into the following
SUMPRODUCT(VacationImport!M1:M1000*(VacationImport!B1:B1000=$E295)*(VacationImport!H1:H1000="Taken")*(VacationImport!C1:C1000="Vacation")*MMULT(N(VacationImport!N1:AF1000=H$2),ROW(1:19)^0))

this assumes a 1,000 row dataset since full-column references should not be used with the SUMPRODUCT() function - if you cannot hard-code the actual last row of the dataset, because it may be dynamic, then I suggest you designate it as an Excel table, and 're-engineer' the formula to use structured references.
Please note that, if you're using Excel 2019 or earlier, then the abbreviated formula would require your larger formula to be entered as an array formula.
(if you are using a new version of Excel, then you should definitely explore the LET() function, in view of the duplication)
Given the number of fixed cell references in your formula I imagine that it will be copied to multiple cells - if this is the case then I would suggest entering the volatile TODAY() function in only 1 single cell in your workbook, and then referencing that cell, instead of the TODAY() function, in all formulae which require it.

If using a newer version of Excel, you could also simplify with BYCOL: SUM(BYCOL(VacationImport!$N:$AF, LAMBDA(_c, SUMIFS(VacationImport!$M:$M, VacationImport!$B:$B, $E295, VacationImport!$H:$H, "Taken", VacationImport!$C:$C, "Vacation", _c, H$2))))

Tried your suggestion.  And I love the shortening, let me tell you.  However, 2 things:  I did have to update to absolute cell references for some of it, and that's not important, but, when I update the range to extend beyond the end of my data, the formula errors out.  I don't really understand N or MMULT (yet), so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot those, but I changed the references from 1000 to 3000 (my current data set goes to about 1300, but I need to leave rrom to grow), and that's when it errored out.  Suggestions?

@ASI_Paving_HR I can say that the issue is not with having blank cells at the end of your range, since the test data I used only comprised 10 rows. My formula would produce errors if all of the data ranges were not of the same size, i.e. in making your updates, did you ensure that you updated the 1000 to 3000 in all 5 places? If you still have issues, then please include your version of the formula in a reply to this.

@ASI_Paving_HR MMULT() returns the product of multiplying 2 matrices, viz. the 19-column wide N:AF range (tested for whether its cells = H$2; the N() converts the resultant TRUE values to 1, and FALSE values to 0) and the 19-row deep array (returned by ROW(1:19)^0) - in the context of my formula this evaluates to a 1,000 row (and single column array) consisting of 1s where there was a match to H$2 and 0s otherwise.
